# Alternative to obsolete ForSqlServerUseSequenceHiLo()?

Tags: .net, .net-core, documentation, deprecated, obsolete

I'm using .NET Core 3 and so when trying to utilize `ForSqlServerUseSequenceHiLo()`, the method does not exist in the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` namespace (or in the `SqlServerPropertyBuilderExtensions` extention).

The documentation notes that [this is now deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserverpropertybuilderextensions.forsqlserverusesequencehilo?view=efcore-3.0) but it doesn't specify an alternative. What may I utilize to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new method is called simply UseHiLo().